# App Engine Connected Android Project - Libraries source attachment

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-c2dm

I'm new to Android and App Engine, I'm trying to create an App Engine Connected Android Project, following the steps described here:

http://code.google.com/intl/es-ES/eclipse/docs/appengine_connected_android.html

but I'm not able to go through the "Say Hello" step (Run & Debug:7) using C2DM, since it prompts a SocketException ("Address family not supported by protocol") and sometimes a RuntimeException when debugging it locally... I don't get it, because I didn't customize the project yet, but after some debugging I saw that it was complaining about some libraries (included at the project creation) not having a source attachment... The most annoying part is that it complains about ThreadPoolExecutor.class, which belongs to java.util.concurrent in the Android 2.2 JAR... Weird, but anyway I attached the library to its source and it keeps complaining about the same class ("The source attachment does not contain the source for the file ThreadPoolExecutor.class")...

It seems to crash in the Util.getRequestFactory() method, at the execution of the first line. Here it calls a method in RequestFactorySource, which belongs to the requestfactory-client library, included at the project creation but again, without a source attachment... By the way, after executing that method call, the "task" variable is valued null, is it normal?

I guess it is about a small error in the configuration or something, but I've been struggling with it for days and I already don't know what to do, so any help would be appreciated :)

**EDIT:** I'm attaching the logcat output, I hope this makes it easier to find the bug. After googling I found out that it is a common error in the C2DM sample project, but I didn't get any appropiate solution.

```
    I/C2dmftwActivity(  333): onCreate
    I/ActivityManager(   58): Displayed activity com.c2dmftw/.C2dmftwActivity: 1281
    ms (total 1281 ms)
    D/dalvikvm(  126): GC_EXPLICIT freed 997 objects / 54032 bytes in 83ms
    W/dalvikvm(  333): threadid=7: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4
    001d800)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while exec
    uting doInBackground()
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:20
    0)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSet
    Exception(FutureTask.java:273)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(
    FutureTask.java:124)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
    (FutureTask.java:307)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTas
    k.java:137)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWo
    rker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worke
    r.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1096)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFacto
    ry ValidationTool must be run for the com.c2dmftw.client.MyRequestFactory Reques
    tFactory type
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.impl
    .Deobfuscator$Builder.load(Deobfuscator.java:59)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.InPr
    ocessRequestFactory.<init>(InProcessRequestFactory.java:80)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at com.google.web.bindery.requestfactory.vm.Requ
    estFactorySource.create(RequestFactorySource.java:43)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at com.c2dmftw.Util.getRequestFactory(Util.java:
    158)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at com.c2dmftw.C2dmftwActivity$2$1.doInBackgroun
    d(C2dmftwActivity.java:144)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at com.c2dmftw.C2dmftwActivity$2$1.doInBackgroun
    d(C2dmftwActivity.java:1)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:18
    5)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun
    (FutureTask.java:305)
    E/AndroidRuntime(  333):        ... 4 more
    W/ActivityManager(   58):   Force finishing activity com.c2dmftw/.C2dmftwActivit
    y
    W/GTalkService(  170): [GTalkConnection.13] doConnect: caught XMPPError connecti
    ng to mtalk.google.com:5228.: (502)
    W/GTalkService(  170):   -- caused by: java.net.SocketException: The operation t
    imed out
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the same problem. The Validation library was missing and after adding it manually it worked.

To add it or to check if it's included do:
Right click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries Tab > Add External JARs

Then browser to your GWT installation folder. If you installed it with eclipse it's in eclipse/plugins/com.google.gwt.eclipse.sdkbundle_/gwt-/validation-api-1.0.0.GA.jar

Clean and build your workspace and try it again.

This could happen on the client GWT side too. If that happens you have to do the same but use your GAE project and add the same jar

Answer (score 0):

This is the problem

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: The RequestFacto
    ry ValidationTool must be run for the com.c2dmftw.client.MyRequestFactory Reques
    tFactory type
```

If you are using GWT 2.4+, you will have to run a validation tool.  You can configure Eclipse to do this for you, here is how:

http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/RequestFactoryInterfaceValidation